# Silent clicking not working on macOS

Tags: trackpad

Specs:

- MacBook Air M1 2020
- macOS Monterey 12.3.1

[image: Image of Trackpad System Preferences panel with option "Silent clicking" selected]

In `System Preferences -> Trackpad`, I have the option *Silent clicking* enabled, but there is no difference in the trackpad  clicking sound.

I have tried:

- restarting the machine
- muting the speakers
- putting one finger on the top of the trackpad and clicking with another finger in the middle of the trackpad as suggested in [this thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7346513)

Answer (score 2):

Old post, but as far as I know, the M1/M2 Apple Silicon-based MacBooks and MacBook Pros don't have a silent mode anymore. In macOS Ventura, you don't get the silent option, just light, medium, and firm. I've tested at least a dozen, and no silent option. The only thing I'm not sure of is the newest Magic Trackpad since there isn't an option in System Settings.

It bugs the heck out of me, but I just learned to ignore it when in light setting.

Comment: I think this is correct. I have a 2020 M1 MBP on Monterey 12.6 and the option is no longer there. Maybe Apple realized it was useless for certain models and removed it sometime after 12.3.1 (from the screenshot in the question). I do recall using the option for a 2015 13" MBP before though. Apple's [support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204352) also says that it's only available for "some Mac laptops".